# VS 2012 and .NET 3.5 without SP1

Tags: .net, visual-studio-2012

Is it possible to limit a VS 2012 project to .NET 3.5 without SP1?
I tried to indicate such limitation in app.config in  config element, but since I guess .NET 3.5 under windows 8 contains all SP1 fixes, it doesn't helped.

Comment: Care to explain what you're trying to achieve?

Comment: [.NET Framework product support lifecycle](http://support.microsoft.com/lifecycle/search/?sort=pn&alpha=.net+framework): "Support for the .NET Framework 3.x versions prior to 3.5 SP1 will remain supported until July 12th, 2011. After this date, support will end;"